# Mutt Cache size Limit for header's and messages

Tags: caching, header, mutt

I've searched high and low on Google for this and can only find `header_cache` for setting the cache dir only. I need to find a way to set the max size of the header cache and the max size of the message cache dir. That one I cannot find.

I can turn off header cache using:

```
folder-hook =spam 'set header_cache=""'
```

But I don't want to turn it off, I just want to limit it's size :(

Answer (score 0):

I use neomutt and not mutt. It's not [possible in neomutt](https://neomutt.org/guide/optionalfeatures.html#7-4-%C2%A0maintenance) and I believe it's the same with mutt